# fetching an element out of a dictionary output

Tags: python

while fetching data i use the following code

`kite.margins(segment='equity')`

the output for this is a dictionary which is below:

```
{'enabled': True,
 'net': 40089.43,
 'available': {'adhoc_margin': 0,
  'cash': 40089.43,
  'opening_balance': 40089.43,
  'live_balance': 40089.43,
  'collateral': 0,
  'intraday_payin': 0},
 'utilised': {'debits': 0,
  'exposure': 0,
  'm2m_realised': 0,
  'm2m_unrealised': 0,
  'option_premium': 0,
  'payout': 0,
  'span': 0,
  'holding_sales': 0,
  'turnover': 0,
  'liquid_collateral': 0,
  'stock_collateral': 0}}
```

I want to fetch the live_balance element of this dictionary and make it variable. 
Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
result = kite.margins(segment='equity')
live_balance = result['available']['live_balance']
```